# Fill the value of a data frame column with value of based upon the column condition

Tags: python, pandas

How to fill the column value of a data frame by comparing the value of the column.

```
Kpi_date cell_name call_Drop
2016-01-08  bgl_1238   0.3
2016-01-08  bgl_1233   0.7
2016-01-08  bgl_1245      
2016-01-08  bgl_1256   1.2
```

I want to fill the value of the `call_Drop` column with 0 when the value is blank.

Comment: What about `df['call_Drop'].fillna(0)`? Is that your dataframe from pandas? Usually missing values filling with NaNs by default

Comment: How to fill other than nan say space character

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert all values in your `call_Drop` column to numeric with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method with `errors=coerce` to convert to `NaN` all non numeric values and then use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
     Kpi_date cell_name call_Drop
0  2016-01-08  bgl_1238       0.3
1  2016-01-08  bgl_1233       0.7
2  2016-01-08  bgl_1245          
3  2016-01-08  bgl_1256       1.2

df.call_Drop = pd.to_numeric(df.call_Drop).fillna(0)

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
     Kpi_date cell_name  call_Drop
0  2016-01-08  bgl_1238        0.3
1  2016-01-08  bgl_1233        0.7
2  2016-01-08  bgl_1245        0.0
3  2016-01-08  bgl_1256        1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['call_Drop'] == '' , 'call_Drop'] = 0
print df

     Kpi_date cell_name call_Drop
0  2016-01-08  bgl_1238       0.3
1  2016-01-08  bgl_1233       0.7
2  2016-01-08  bgl_1245         0
3  2016-01-08  bgl_1256       1.2
```

Or [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with condition not contains `empty space`:

```
df['call_Drop'] = df['call_Drop'].where(df['call_Drop'] != '', 0) 
print df

     Kpi_date cell_name call_Drop
0  2016-01-08  bgl_1238       0.3
1  2016-01-08  bgl_1233       0.7
2  2016-01-08  bgl_1245         0
3  2016-01-08  bgl_1256       1.2
```

Or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
print df
     Kpi_date cell_name call_Drop
0  2016-01-08  bgl_1238       0.3
1  2016-01-08  bgl_1233       0.7
2  2016-01-08  bgl_1245          
3  2016-01-08  bgl_1256       1.2

df['call_Drop'] = df['call_Drop'].replace('', 0)
print df

     Kpi_date cell_name  call_Drop
0  2016-01-08  bgl_1238        0.3
1  2016-01-08  bgl_1233        0.7
2  2016-01-08  bgl_1245        0.0
3  2016-01-08  bgl_1256        1.2
```

---

But maybe value is not `empty space` but `space`, then condition is changed to:

```
df.loc[df['call_Drop'] == ' ' , 'call_Drop'] = 0
```

Or if there is `spaces`, more as one:

```
df['call_Drop'] = df['call_Drop'].replace(r'\s+', 0, regex=True)
```